# Nginx Redirect Chaining

Tags: nginx

This is What I have

```
http://example.com ---> https://www.example.com ---> https://example.com
```

This is what I am trying to Achieve

```
http://example.com ---> https://example.com
```

My current nginx config has the below mentioned line

```
if ($real_scheme = 'http') { return 301 https://$host$request_uri; }
```

Where real_scheme is a variable derived from a Map block

I am trying to Achieve the same using a Map, can anyone lemme know the mistake I am making, Below is the updated Config

```
map $host $nonwwwhost {
~*^www\.(.*)   $1;   
default     $host;
}

if ($real_scheme = 'http') { return 301 https://$nonwwwhost$request_uri; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out a way to Achieve this using regex expression

```
map $host $nonwwwhost {
~*^www\.(?<domain3>\S+)*  $domain3;
default     $host;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say that using `map` for https redirects is discouraged, because the standard practice is allocating `server` blocks with redirects set up inside them.

There are a total of 3 server blocks required to cover redirecting to your desired canonical domain name and port.

Redirections flow can be different, but I suggest following with [HSTS redirect requirements](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/security/dissecting-https-redirect-requirements-of-hsts).

In a case where your canonical domain is example.com and not [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), these would be your server blocks:

```
server {
    listen 80; 
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    more_set_headers "Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload";
    ssl_certificate ...;
    ssl_certificate_key ...;
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 80; 
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    more_set_headers "Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload";
    ssl_certificate ...;
    ssl_certificate_key ...;
    server_name example.com;
    ... main website directives go here
}
```

This kind of setup ensures, that should a visitor first access **http:**//www.example.com, he is first redirected to **https:**//www.example.com and then https://example.com, ensuring his browser obtains HSTS policy accordingly.

Comment: But I do not want to hardcode example.com as permanent instead would like to use $host so that sub domains are also included